# Incompatible server issue on MySQL Workbench (10.4.27). I am trying to use mysql_upgrade to resolve but cannot get this to work

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench

I am trying to run a local website on localhost 3307 through XAMPP. I have configured MySQL server to port 3307 in XAMPP and this is running successfully. The issue seems to be related to MySQL workbench where I cannot use certain features due to an "incompatible server issue".

I have searched how to resolve this for a long time and everything seems to suggest running mysql_upgrade. For my Mac, the file path is /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_upgrade

However, when I run this, I receive the error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Could not open or create the upgrade info file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql_upgrade_info' in the MariaDB Servers data directory, errno: 13 (Permission denied)
Note that mysql_upgrade should be run as the same user as the MariaDB server binary, normally 'mysql' or 'root'.
Alternatively you can use mysql_upgrade --force --force. Please check the documentation if you decide to use the force option!
```

I am hoping that mysql_upgrade can resolve the workbench issue and allow me to connect the website to the local database. I cannot access large parts of the local website until I can connect to all of the database features.

I have also tried to import the database by "reverse engineer". This allows me to see a model of the tables, but I still cannot connect to the database properly so the website can function.